# mongodb embedded update object

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this structure:

```
{
 "_id": NumberInt(101),
 "link_id": {
 "125": {
   "thumb_position": NumberInt(1),
   "last_scan": NumberInt(1234563645),
   "row_numb": NumberInt(301),
   "clicks": NumberInt(120)
   },
 "126": {
   "thumb_position": NumberInt(2),
   "last_scan": NumberInt(-2147483648),
   "row_numb": NumberInt(1301),
   "clicks": NumberInt(199)
     },
    {
    ...
    }
}
}
```

and I want to update the document with new linkids and get:

```
{
"_id": NumberInt(101),
"link_id": {
  "125": {
   "thumb_position": NumberInt(1),
   "last_scan": NumberInt(1234563645),
   "row_numb": NumberInt(301),
   "clicks": NumberInt(120)
},
 "126": {
   "thumb_position": NumberInt(2),
   "last_scan": NumberInt(-2147483648),
   "row_numb": NumberInt(1301),
   "clicks": NumberInt(199)
},
 "127": {
   "thumb_position": NumberInt(1),
   "last_scan": NumberInt(-2147483628),
   "row_numb": NumberInt(1304),
   "clicks": NumberInt(195)
}
}
```

I have tried in php:

```
$value = array (
'130' => 
array (
  'thumb_position' => 1,
  'last_scan' => 1234563640,
  'row_numb' => 300,
  'clicks' => 120,
));
$update_status = $collection->update( array('_id'=>intval(101)), array('$set' => array('link_id' => $value)) , array("upsert"=>true ,"multiple"=> true , "safe"=> true) );
```

but this is only overwriting the link_ids with this 130.

the embedded aproach... since this is not an array, but objects, any idea on how to solve this? Thx a lot.

Comment: What happens if you use array('$set' => array('link_id.130' => $value['130'])) instead?

Comment: thx @nutlike for your answer. I try this and the result was: `code`  {
   "_id": NumberInt(100),
   "link_id": {
     "129": {
       "thumb_position": NumberInt(1),
       "last_scan": NumberInt(1234563649),
       "row_numb": NumberInt(309),
       "clicks": NumberInt(129)
    },
     "130": null
  }
} 
 the value was:  `code` $value_i = array (
      'thumb_position' => 1,
      'last_scan' => 1234563641,
      'row_numb' => 301,
      'clicks' => 121,
    ); so it added a null entrance. Guess the way is around. Thx again.

Comment: its now working.. just like u said... not using the  'code' $value_i = array ( 'thumb_position' => 1, 'last_scan' => 1234563641, 'row_numb' => 301, 'clicks' => 121, ); but the 'code' $value['130'].. dont get the difference... thx a lot!

Comment: to delete one of those embedded entries would be: `code` $update_status = $collection->update( array('_id'=>intval(100), 'link_id'=> "133"), array('$set' => array('link_id.133' => null)) , array("upsert"=>true ,"multiple"=> true , "safe"=> true) ); ?

Comment: You should use $unset in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code instead:

```
$value = array (
    'thumb_position' => 1,
    'last_scan' => 1234563640,
    'row_numb' => 300,
    'clicks' => 120,
);

$update_status = $collection->update(
    array('_id'=>intval(101)),
    array('$set' => array('link_id.130' => $value)),
    array("upsert"=>true ,"multiple"=> true , "safe"=> true)
);
```